# Should I use degree name as their system?

Tags: statement-of-purpose, degree, titles, canada

I am writing Statement of Purpose for PhD application to Canadian university and I am stumbling over a little issue that when I write like this

> I have completed my masters degree ...  after completing bachelors
>   degree..

So should I write undergraduate/graduate degree word as what they say at their place or I use words that what they say at my place as I written above? or either one is okey?

Comment: "Undergraduate" and "graduate" mean different things in different places. Just use the program names as they were at the schools you attended if you want to be unambiguous.

Comment: I agree with @aeismail - write what actually happened. It might be worth also adding what the equivalence is. PS. (stating the obvious) Unless your written English/French is rather better than in this question, it isn't going to matter anyway.

Comment: @aeismail sounds like an answer...

Comment: @JessicaB what I wrote above is indeed a hint to say i m going to write about this. I will write what they called it in my university and with adding academic elegance to the language. Thanks :)

Comment: @ff524 I agree that both comments making the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is better to use the exact phrases and words mentioned your documents and degrees. If the words *bachelors* and *masters* degrees are written in your certificates; simply use these words. It is much more sure and easier than thinking about rephrasing the words or finding synonyms for them. Also, in my opinion; bachelors and masters degrees are more explicit words than undergraduate and graduate degrees.